# Remote Desktop via Ad-Hoc on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, remote-desktop, ad-hoc-network

Is there a way to connect two PCs running Windows 7 via a wifi ad-hoc network and then use Remote Desktop from one of the PCs to the other? In addition to this the Remote Desktop host PC should still be able to connect to the internet via a separate ethernet adapter, allowing the client to use the internet via the remote host screen.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the wired and wireless networks should stay separate, with different
IP segments per each network.

You should then bridge the two adapters on the PC that has the Internet access.
See [How to Bridge From a Wireless to a Hard-Wired LAN](http://www.ehow.com/how_8697975_bridge-wireless-hardwired-lan.html).

This should enable the client PC to use the Internet connection of the other one.
I am not too clear about using Remote Desktop in this setup, so just try and see.

Comment: I tried bridging the adapters, setting up the Ad-Hoc network, and connecting the client PC to the network. I was able to connect to the network and use the internet from the client PC but as soon as I tried to connect Remote Desktop the ad-hoc network shut down and the connection was lost on the client.

Comment: Ad-hoc is defined as a temporary connection, but I believe that RDP should still work. Are you getting an error message with the disconnect? Anything in the Event Viewer? Are you using only Windows or 3rd-party software? Try also using static IP addresses for both computers.

Comment: How do I use static IP addresses?

Comment: Here is [a tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/19249/how-to-assign-a-static-ip-address-in-xp-vista-or-windows-7/). Choose values that are in the right segment - use ipconfig in a command prompt on both computers to find out which is the segment to use.

Answer (score -1):

This should absolutely be possible. Just set the ad-hoc network on a different IP range (for example, use `192.168.2.1` and `192.168.2.2` as the IPs for the two computers, and set the subnet mask to `255.255.255.0`). The host must be able to run a Remote Desktop server (which I believe is restricted to Pro and up), but you can have a computer connected to two networks.

Comment: I would describe that as a different IP, rather than a different IP *range*.

Comment: @Dan I meant "use the range `192.168.2.x`" (as opposed to `192.168.1.x`). The right term would be "different network" or "different subnet", but "different range" is less confusing.

Comment: This is promising but could you be more specific, How do I set these IP parameters?

Comment: @StickFigs In Windows, under "Network Connections", right click the wireless interface, and hit "Properties". Click "TCP/IP version 4", and hit the configure button. Then, select "Manual IP" and enter these.

Comment: @cpast I tried setting the host IP to 192.168.2.1 but when I connect the other PC to the ad-hoc network it resets to the default IP 192.168.137.Something. You said to set the IP on both PCs? Before or after connecting/creating the network?

Comment: After creating it.

Comment: @cpast On both PCs or just the host?

Comment: Do it on both PCs.

Comment: @cpast It doesn't work. I set the host to `192.168.2.1` subnet mask `255.255.255.0` and the client to `192.168.2.2` same subnet mask. The client can connect to the Ad-Hoc network but it can't access the shared internet or even ping the host's IP. The host can't ping the client either.